# Editar registro con php y mysqli no funciona

Tags: php, mysqli, update

tengo el siguiente código:

editar.php lo que deberia hacer el codigo seria editar el registro, pero cada vez que intento me arroja el mensaje 'Los campos están vacíos ' y no hace el proceso de update.

```
<?php
    include_once 'conexion.php';

    if(isset($_GET['id'])){
        $id=(int) $_GET['id'];

        $buscar_id=$con->prepare('SELECT * FROM cita WHERE id=:id LIMIT 1');
        $buscar_id->execute(array(
            ':id'=>$id
        ));
        $resultado=$buscar_id->fetch();
    }else{
        header('Location: citas.php');
    }

    if(isset($_POST['guardar'])){
        echo$asunto=$_POST['asunto'];
        echo$paciente=$_POST['paciente'];
        echo$fecha=$_POST['fecha'];
        echo$enfermedad=$_POST['enfermedad'];
        echo$nota=$_POST['nota'];
        echo$doctores=$_POST['doctores'];
        echo$hora=$_POST['hora'];
        echo$sintomas=$_POST['sintomas'];
        $id=(int) $_GET['id'];

        if(!empty($asunto) && !empty($paciente) && !empty($fecha) && !empty($enfermedad) && !empty($nota) && !empty($doctores) && !empty($hora) && !empty($sintomas) ){
            if(!filter_var($asunto)){
                echo "<script> alert('no valido');</script>";
            }else{
                $consulta_update=$con->prepare('UPDATE cita SET  
                    asunto=:asunto,
                    nombre_pac=:paciente,
                    fecha=:fecha,
                    enfermedad=:enfermedad,
                    nota=:nota,
                    nombre_med=:doctores,
                    hora=:hora,
                    sintomas=:sintomas
                    WHERE id=:id;'
                );
                $consulta_update->execute(array(
                    ':asunto' =>$asunto,
                    ':nombre_pac' =>$paciente,
                    ':fecha' =>$fecha,
                    ':enfermedad' =>$enfermedad,
                    ':nota' =>$nota,
                    ':nombre_med' =>$doctores,
                    ':hora' =>$hora,
                    ':sintomas' =>$sintomas,
                    ':id' =>$id
                ));
                header('Location: citas.php');
            }
        }else{
            echo "<script> alert('Los campos estan vacios');</script>";
        }
    }

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Editar Datos</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilo1.css">
</head>
<?php include('conexion.php'); ?>
<body>
    <div class="contenedor">
        <h2>Editar Cita</h2>

        <form method="post" action="updatecita.php?id=<?php echo $id?>">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="asunto" value="<?php if($resultado) echo $resultado['asunto']; ?>" class="input__text">
            </div>
                <div class="form-group input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:120px;">Nombre Paciente:</span>
                            <select style="width:400px;" class="form-control" name="paciente">
                                <option value="<?php echo $resultado['nombre_pac']?>"><?php echo $resultado['nombre_pac']; ?></option>
                                <?php
                                    $c=mysqli_query($con,"select * from paciente");
                                    while($crow=mysqli_fetch_array($c)){
                                        ?>
                                            <option value="<?php echo $crow['nombre']; ?>"><?php echo $crow['nombre']; ?></option>
                                        <?php
                                    }
                                ?>
                            </select>
                        </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="fecha" value="<?php if($resultado) echo $resultado['fecha']; ?>" class="input__text">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="enfermedad" value="<?php if($resultado) echo $resultado['enfermedad']; ?>" class="input__text">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="nota" value="<?php if($resultado) echo $resultado['nota']; ?>" class="input__text">
            </div>
                  <div class="form-group input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:120px;">Nombre Medico:</span>
                            <select style="width:400px;" class="form-control" name="doctores" name="apellido">
                                <option value="<?php if($resultado)['nombre_med']?>"><?php echo $resultado['nombre_med']; ?></option>
                                <?php
                                    $c=mysqli_query($con,"select * from doctores");
                                    while($crow=mysqli_fetch_array($c)){
                                        ?>
                                            <option value="<?php echo $crow['nombre']; ?>"><?php echo $crow['nombre']; ?></option>
                                        <?php
                                    }
                                ?>
                            </select>
                        </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="hora" value="<?php if($resultado) echo $resultado['hora']; ?>" class="input__text">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="sintomas" value="<?php if($resultado) echo $resultado['sintomas']; ?>" class="input__text">
            </div>
            <div class="btn__group">
                <a href="citas.php" class="btn btn__danger">Cancelar</a>
                <input type="submit" name="guardar" value="Guardar" class="btn btn__primary">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Que podría tener mal en mi código? cualquier ayuda me seria de gran utilidad muchas gracias.

Comment: Saludos. Salvo que yo declaro `name` e `ìd` a cada elemento; veo que usted solo le tiene `name` no le veo otra cosa.

Comment: ¿Estas seguro de que todos los campos tienen datos? Porque si al menos uno esta vacio, eso provocaría que siempre salte dicho mensaje. **PD:** Tenes un error de sintaxis en la consulta `... WHERE id=:id;'`, tenes un `;` de mas.

Comment: Buenas tardes, aun me da el mismo error ya hice todo lo que me indicaron, igualmente muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero, asegúrate de que se recibió ID por parámetro y que es válido, además de definir la variable desde el inicio del script, para que esté disponible más adelante.

En caso de que se encuentre el registro, define variables con el mismo nombre de los campos en el formulario, tal como haces con $_POST.

```
<?php
include_once 'conexion.php';
// Definir ID y resultado desde el inicio
$id = (isset($_GET['id'])) ? (int) $_GET['id'] : 0;
$resultado = false;
if($id > 0) {
    $buscar_id=$con->prepare('SELECT * FROM cita WHERE id=:id LIMIT 1');
    $buscar_id->execute(array(
        ':id' => $id
    ));
    if($resultado=$buscar_id->fetch()) {
        // Inicializa aquí todas tus variables: asunto, paciente, etc.
        $asunto = $resultado['asunto'];
        $paciente = $resultado['nombre_pac'];
        // ... aquí los que faltan, te servirán para el formulario
    }
}
// Si resultado es falso, quiere decir que ID no se proporcionó o es incorrecto
if($resultado === false) {
    header('Location: citas.php');
    // Debes finalizar el script después de una redirección
    exit;
}
```

Cuando procesas el formulario crea una variable de error, define todas las variables (excepto $id) y verifica que todos los campos son válidos:

```
// Definir variable de error para evitar alertas
$error = '';

if(isset($_POST['guardar'])) {
    $asunto = $_POST['asunto'];
    $paciente = $_POST['paciente'];
    $fecha = $_POST['fecha'];
    $enfermedad = $_POST['enfermedad'];
    $nota = $_POST['nota'];
    $doctores = $_POST['doctores'];
    $hora = $_POST['hora'];
    $sintomas = $_POST['sintomas'];
    // $id = (int) $_GET['id']; // Esto no es necesario, ya está definido y verificado arriba

    // Define un arreglo para almacenar errores específicos:
    $errores = [];
    // Evaluación y asignación en una misma línea
    // Algunos IDEs pueden marcar error y solo hay que cambiar && por and
    (empty($asunto) && $errores[] = '- Asunto no puede estar vacío');
    (empty($paciente) && $errores[] = '- Paciente no puede estar vacío');
    (empty($fecha) && $errores[] = '- Fecha no puede estar vacía');
    (empty($enfermedad) && $errores[] = '- Enfermedad no puede estar vacía');
    (empty($nota) && $errores[] = '- Nota no puede estar vacía');
    (empty($doctores) && $errores[] = '- Doctores no puede estar vacío');
    (empty($hora) && $errores[] = '- Hora no puede estar vacía');
    (empty($sintomas) && $errores[] = '- Síntomas no puede estar vacío');

    if(count($errores) == 0) {
        // No hay errores, puedes procesar
                $consulta_update=$con->prepare('UPDATE cita SET  
                    asunto = :asunto,
                    nombre_pac = :paciente,
                    fecha = :fecha,
                    enfermedad = :enfermedad,
                    nota = :nota,
                    nombre_med = :doctores,
                    hora = :hora,
                    sintomas = :sintomas
                    WHERE id = :id'
                );
                $consulta_update->execute(array(
                    ':asunto' => $asunto,
                    ':nombre_pac' => $paciente,
                    ':fecha' => $fecha,
                    ':enfermedad' => $enfermedad,
                    ':nota' => $nota,
                    ':nombre_med' => $doctores,
                    ':hora' => $hora,
                    ':sintomas' => $sintomas,
                    ':id' => $id
                ));
                header('Location: citas.php');
                // Finalizar script
                exit;
            }
    } else {
        // Crear mensaje de error
        $error = "<p class=\"form-error\">Por favor corrige los siguientes errores:\\n" . implode("<br>\n", $errores) . '</p>';
    }
}
```

Coloca lo siguiente justo arriba del formulario y podrás ver cuáles campos son los que no se llenaron (¿o procesaron?) correctamente:

```
<?php
// Puede ser cadena vacía o mensajes de error que resultaron al procesar
echo $error;
?>
```

Luego, en el formulario, usas las variables que ya tienes:

```
    <form method="post" action="updatecita.php?id=<?php echo $id?>">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="asunto" value="<?php echo $asunto; ?>" class="input__text">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:120px;">Nombre Paciente:</span>
            <select style="width:400px;" class="form-control" name="paciente">
                <option value="<?php echo $paciente; ?>"><?php echo $paciente; ?></option>
<?php
        $c=mysqli_query($con,"select * from paciente");
        while($crow=mysqli_fetch_array($c)){
?>
                <option value="<?php echo $crow['nombre']; ?>"><?php echo $crow['nombre']; ?></option>
<?php
        }
?>
            </select>
        </div>
```

De esta forma conservas los datos originales de base de datos o los cambios que se hayan hecho al procesar el formulario.

Solo para asegurar que todo está bien, verifica que la consulta se ejecutó:

```
            if($consulta_update->execute(array(
                ':asunto' => $asunto,
                ':nombre_pac' => $paciente,
                ':fecha' => $fecha,
                ':enfermedad' => $enfermedad,
                ':nota' => $nota,
                ':nombre_med' => $doctores,
                ':hora' => $hora,
                ':sintomas' => $sintomas,
                ':id' => $id
            ))) {
                header('Location: citas.php');
                // Finalizar script
                exit;
           } else {
               $error = '<p class="form-error">No se pudo ejecutar la consulta.</p>';
            }
```