# Recarga de página sin que inicialice inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Buenas tardes: Tengo una página HTML que utiliza los datos de un input, varios checkboxes y radiobuttons para realizar cálculos y luego pasar los resultados a 4 inputs, todo lo hago en la misma página utilizando el método htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) por medio de un botón.
Lo que deseo es que al momento de realizar los cálculos y se recargue la página no se reinicien los valores del input, los checkboxes y los radiobuttons.
Leí que se podría utilizar header("Cache-Control:"), ¿Alguien podría ayudarme indicándome los valores que se deben utilizar?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Equipo Computo</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css"/>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.4.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script>

        $(document).ready(function() {
            var costo_total = $("#costo_total").val();
            var impuesto = $("#impuesto").val();
            var total_pagar = $("#total_pagar").val();
            var monto_cuotas = $("#monto_cuotas").val();

            if (costo_total > 0) {
                $('#costo_total').val(number_format(costo_total,2));
                $('#impuesto').val(number_format(impuesto,2));
                $('#total_pagar').val(number_format(total_pagar,2));
                $('#monto_cuotas').val(number_format(monto_cuotas,2));
            };

            $(".container_pago_cuotas input").click(function () {    
                var forma_pago = $('input:radio[name=forma_pago]:checked').val();

                switch (forma_pago) {
                    case 'contado':
                        limpia_cuotas();
                        break;

                    case 'credito':
                        $('#6cuota').prop('checked', true);
                        break;
                }
            });

            $("#btn_limpiar").on('click', function() {
                limpia_inputs();
            });

        });

        function limpia_cuotas() {
            $("input[name='cuotas']").each(function(){
                if($(this).val() !== "1"){
                    $(this).prop("checked",false);
                }
            });
        }

        function limpia_inputs() {
            $('#costo_total').val('0,00');
            $('#impuesto').val('0,00');
            $('#total_pagar').val('0,00');
            $('#monto_cuotas').val('0,00');
        }
    
        function number_format(amount, decimals) {
            amount += ''; // por si pasan un numero en vez de un string
            amount = parseFloat(amount.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '')); // elimino cualquier cosa que no sea numero o punto

            decimals = decimals || 0; // por si la variable no fue pasada

            // si no es un numero o es igual a cero retorno el mismo cero
            if (isNaN(amount) || amount === 0) 
                return parseFloat(0).toFixed(decimals);

                // si es mayor o menor que cero retorno el valor formateado como numero
                amount = '' + amount.toFixed(decimals);

                var amount_parts = amount.split('.'),
                regexp = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;

                while (regexp.test(amount_parts[0]))
                    amount_parts[0] = amount_parts[0].replace(regexp, '$1' + '.' + '$2');

                return amount_parts.join(',');

        }

    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])?>" method="post" id="form_calculo">
                    <div class="row container_costo_computadora justify-content-center">
                        <div class="col-3">
                            <label class=" d-flex justify-content-center" for="costo_computador">Costo de la Computadora</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="costo_computador" id="costo_computador" value="" autocomplete="off" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <hr>
                    
                    <div class="row container_titulos_accesorios">
                        <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center">
                            <h6 for="title_accesorios">Accesorios:</h6>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row container_accesorios justify-content-center">
                        <div class="col-6 d-flex justify-content-around">
                            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                <label class="form-check-label">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="cb_imp" value="impresora"> Impresora
                                </label>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                <label class="form-check-label">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="cb_esc" value="scanner"> Scanner
                                </label>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                <label class="form-check-label">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="cb_est" value="estabilizador"> Estabilizador
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <hr>

                    <div class="row container_titulos_pagos_cuotas justify-content-center">
                        <div class="col-4 d-flex justify-content-center">
                            <h6 for="title_accesorios">Forma de Pago:</h6>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-4 d-flex justify-content-center">
                            <h6 for="title_accesorios">Número de Cuotas:</h6>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="row container_pago_cuotas justify-content-center">
                        <div class="col-4 d-flex justify-content-center pagos">
                            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                <label class="form-check-label">
                                    <input type="radio" name="forma_pago" id="credito" value="credito"> Crédito
                                </label>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                <label class="form-check-label">
                                    <input type="radio" name="forma_pago" id="contado" value="contado"> Contado
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-4 d-flex justify-content-center cuotas">
                            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                <label class="form-check-label">
                                    <input type="radio" name="cuotas" id="6cuota" value="6"> 6
                                </label>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                <label class="form-check-label">
                                    <input type="radio" name="cuotas" id="12cuota" value="12"> 12
                                </label>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                <label class="form-check-label">
                                    <input type="radio" name="cuotas" id="18cuota" value="18"> 18
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <hr>

                    <div class="row container_botones justify-content-center">
                        <div class="col-2">
                            <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-success" id="btn_calcular">CALCULAR</button>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-2">
                            <button class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-info" id="btn_limpiar">LIMPIAR</button>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-2">
                            <button class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-danger" id="btn_cerrar">CERRAR</button>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-2">
                            <button class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-warning" id="btn_cerrar">VOLVER</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <hr>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col container_titulos_totales">
                            <div class="row titulos_totales">
                                <div class="col d-flex justify-content-end">
                                    <label>Costo Total: </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row titulos_totales">
                                <div class="col d-flex justify-content-end">
                                    <label>Impuesto IGV: </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row titulos_totales">
                                <div class="col d-flex justify-content-end">
                                    <label>Precio a Pagar: </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row titulos_totales">
                                <div class="col d-flex justify-content-end">
                                    <label>Monto de las Cuotas: </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col container_inputs_totales">
                            <div class="row inputs_totales">
                                <div class="col-4">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="costo_total" id="costo_total" value="0,00">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row inputs_totales">
                                <div class="col-4">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="impuesto" id="impuesto" value="0,00">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row inputs_totales">
                                <div class="col-4">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="total_pagar" id="total_pagar"value="0,00">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row inputs_totales">
                                <div class="col-4">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="monto_cuotas" id="monto_cuotas"value="0,00">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>

    <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="js/functions.js"></script> -->

</body>
</html>

<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        $precioComputadora = $_POST['costo_computador'];
        $formaPago = $_POST['forma_pago'];

    // Variables Generales
        $iva = 0.19;
        $impresora = 240;
        $estabilizador = 80;
        $scanner = 150;
        $descuentoContado = 0.06;

    // Variables Accesorios
        if (empty($_POST['cb_imp'])) {
            $accImp = 0;
        } else {
            $accImp = $impresora;
        }

        if (empty($_POST['cb_esc'])) {
            $accScan = 0;
        } else {
            $accScan = $scanner;
        }

        if (empty($_POST['cb_est'])) {
            $accEst = 0;
        } else {
            $accEst = $estabilizador;
        }

        $totalAccesorios = ($accImp + $accScan + $accEst);

        if (empty($_POST['cuotas'])) {
            $cuotas = 0;
        } else {
            $cuotas = $_POST['cuotas'];
        }

        switch ($formaPago) {
            case 'contado':
                $descuentoMonto = ($precioComputadora * $descuentoContado);
                $precioFinalComputadora = ($precioComputadora - $descuentoMonto);
                $totalCompra = ($precioFinalComputadora + $totalAccesorios);
                $totalIVA = ($totalCompra * $iva);
                $totalPagar = ($totalCompra + $totalIVA);
                $montoCuota = "0,00";
                echo '<script type="text/javascript">
                        $("#costo_total").val('.$totalCompra.');
                        $("#impuesto").val('.$totalIVA.');
                        $("#total_pagar").val('.$totalPagar.');
                      </script>';
                break;
            
            case 'credito':
                if ($cuotas == 6) {
                    $totalCompra = $precioComputadora + $totalAccesorios;
                    $costoCuotas = ($totalCompra * 0.05);
                    $totalCosto = $totalCompra + $costoCuotas;
                    $totalIVA = ($totalCosto * 0.19);
                    $totalPagar = $totalCosto + $totalIVA;
                    $montoCuotas = ($totalPagar / $cuotas);
                    echo '<script type="text/javascript">
                            $("#costo_total").val('.$totalCosto.');
                            $("#impuesto").val('.$totalIVA.');
                            $("#total_pagar").val('.$totalPagar.');
                            $("#monto_cuotas").val('.$montoCuotas.');
                          </script>';
                } else if ($cuotas == 12) {
                    $totalCompra = $precioComputadora + $totalAccesorios;
                    $costoCuotas = ($totalCompra * 0.06);
                    $totalCosto = $totalCompra + $costoCuotas;
                    $totalIVA = ($totalCosto * 0.19);
                    $totalPagar = $totalCosto + $totalIVA;
                    $montoCuotas = ($totalPagar / $cuotas);
                    echo '<script type="text/javascript">
                            $("#costo_total").val('.$totalCosto.');
                            $("#impuesto").val('.$totalIVA.');
                            $("#total_pagar").val('.$totalPagar.');
                            $("#monto_cuotas").val('.$montoCuotas.');
                          </script>';
                } else if ($cuotas == 18) {
                    $totalCompra = $precioComputadora + $totalAccesorios;
                    $costoCuotas = ($totalCompra * 0.07);
                    $totalCosto = $totalCompra + $costoCuotas;
                    $totalIVA = ($totalCosto * 0.19);
                    $totalPagar = $totalCosto + $totalIVA;
                    $montoCuotas = ($totalPagar / $cuotas);
                    echo '<script type="text/javascript">
                            $("#costo_total").val('.$totalCosto.');
                            $("#impuesto").val('.$totalIVA.');
                            $("#total_pagar").val('.$totalPagar.');
                            $("#monto_cuotas").val('.$montoCuotas.');
                          </script>';
                }
                break;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Para poder ayudarte, por favor edita la pregunta y agrega tu código.

Comment: Triby: Ya coloqué el código

Comment: Revisa [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/368879/editar-registro-con-php-y-mysqli-no-funciona/368897#368897), es más o menos lo mismo. El PHP debe ir al principio para que puedas tomar las variables de base de datos o de $_POST.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que una de las opciones mas sencillas seria hacer un sessionStorage el cual te permite almacenar clave valor y recuperarla desde cualquier punto de la pagina aunque recargue la misma [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) con esto tienes dos opciones.

Añadir la misma cantidad de sessionStorage que datos quieres almacenar y luego recuperarlos o la segunda opción seria serializarlos e un json y almacenarlo en un solo sessionStorage para luego recuperarlo.

Para almacenarlo sin que el usuario interactue puedes utilizar onunload para que cuando se carge la pagina almacene los elementos en sessionStorage [link](https://tinchicus.com/2019/11/13/javascript-onload-onunload/)

Para recuperarlos seria utilizando un onload [introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp)